# how to design database with arrays

Tags: javascript, mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, vue.js

how to design database with arrays
I am developing a meeting organisation application with Vue and was thinking on how to save the values to my DB. I have an entity called MeetingSetting with one meetingSetting having these parameters:

```
    meetingSettings:
    [
    {
    meetingUrl
    meetingPw
    meetingDate[
    {date, time[{start, end}]},
    voters[
    {uniquename,email, availableDate:[{date, time[start,end]}]}
    
    ]

]
}

]
```

So to explain, I will be generating a question for availability this will consists of Dates and multiple time slots connected to the date. Voters can later select dates and times which are available for them. They can have multiple of those entries (dates and times).

I am kinda stuck on how to design my db I thought of doing it with postgresql as it has the function to save arrays, or should I use mysql with multiple tables and then connect with foreign key? Or is my approach completely wrong could someone who knows his way with databases around help me? I will use Spring boot for backend.

Comment: why not just JSON.stringify your arrays and save them as text (JSON)?

Comment: Why not a one-to-many relationship or a many-to-many if different slots can be specified for different meetings as options. Doing this as JSON blobs is often really messy.

Comment: Can you add a clear expected `JSON`?

Comment: Multi-value data fields, such as arrays, JSON docs, XML docs, are suitable to be stored and retrieved as whole units. If you feel there's need to change their content by adding, updating, or removing subelements of them, then it's time to normalize your data model at least to 3NF. Consider a 1:N relationship as @tadman indicates.

Comment: So if I understood you guys correctly, you suggest I do multiple tables right? And then connect them through the id? or name? Did I understood it correctly? I thought doing it with postgresql and saving it whole as an array would be easier or is it wrong of me to think like that? I am a bit new do DB designing

Comment: I will do it @ibrahim AlTamimi

Comment: Hi @The Impaler, what do you mean with 3NF?

Comment: @haso 3NF is short for "Third Normal Form". See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form